# How to open an application weblink with a Wine program

Tags: windows, wine, browser, webapps

I have installed a Windows program (a game called the Hunter) using Wine on Ubuntu 14.04.

The only way to use this game is by going to its website, create the game options and then hitting an application web link on that website that will pass the options and start the local program.

This works in Windows because the program that the web browser calls to open this kind of link is set by default when installing the game.

How do I manage now to get the Wine-installed game to do the same under Ubuntu?

Comment: This appears to be a very specific issue of this very specific game. You will only have a change to get an answer here from somebody who also plays this game. It would therefore be a good idea you [edit] your question to tell us what game this is you want to play.

Comment: @Takkat I have edited the question, but I don't see how this should be different from any other application that can be opened through an application link on a website. I would imagine other Wine users have tried this before for a different program.